# Is it possible to create/join a lobby with 4 people, not on friends list, programmatically? [Steam + CSGO]

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I've got this project on my mind, but before I started doing any real work, I went through steam API docs to see if it was possible to create and invite 4 people that are NOT on the friends list, by ID (or something, users would be logged in through steam), to a competitive lobby of CS:GO.

No luck so far. Am I missing something? Is this possible in any way?

Comment: you ever figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. It is possible only if they have steam and they have purchased CS GO.